# Prove that $S_4 \cong V_4 \rtimes_\phi S_3$ for any isomorphism $\phi: S_3 \to \text{Aut}(V_4)$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, semidirect-product

Note that $\text{Aut}(V_4) \cong S_3$.
I know how to prove that $S_4$ isomorphic to some semidirect product of $V_4$ and $S_3$.
I know if it works for an isomphorism it works for any isomorphism.
However, I'm having trouble seeing that the $\phi$ must be an isomorphism of $\phi: S_3 \to \text{Aut}(V_4)$ (i.e. the kernel is trivial).
Is there a better way to check this without doing each case (kernel cannot be 3-cycles, or all of $S_3$)?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to ask better?  I have trouble understanding this part of the question: "However, I'm having trouble seeing that the $\phi$ must be an isomorphism of $\phi: S_3 \to \text{Aut}(V_4)$ (i.e. the kernel is trivial)."  Are you asking us how to find a good $\phi$?

Comment: If some element of $S_3$ were in the kernel of $\phi$, then that element would commute with all of $V_4$. As $V_4$ is itself abelian you would get an abelian subgroup of  order 8 or 12. $S_4$ has no such subgroups.

Comment: There is of course the direct product $V_4\times S_3$ when $\ker\phi=S_3$ but that isn't isomorphic to $S_4$.

Comment: Ah, I see what @Raekye wanted to ask: Why should every $\phi\colon S_3\xrightarrow{\cong}\operatorname{Aut}(V_4)$ gives $V_4\rtimes_\phi S_3\to S_4$ an isomorphism, without having to do some explicit calculation with elements?  For that, [answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38093/g-rtimes-phi-h-cong-g-rtimes-psi-h-when-certain-automorphisms-exist) would be very helpful.

Comment: @Zvi In general for a semidirect product we just need a homomorphism from $S_3$ to $\text{Aut}(V_4)$. As others have pointed out, the trivial homomorphism gives a direct product of $V_4$ and $S_3$, which is not isomorphic to $S_4$. However, there could be other candidates for homomorphisms that give the semidirect product $V_4 \rtimes S_3 \cong S_4$. The best way I could think of to classify them is by kernels (which have to be normal subgroups). If we show that the kernel of $\phi$ must be trivial, then we know the semidirect product comes from an isomorphism of $S_3 \to \text{Aut}(V_4)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that $S_4 \cong V_4 \rtimes S_3$, first note that $V_4$ is isomorphic to the double transpositions in $S_4$, and this $V_4$ is normal in $S_4$.
Consider an isomorphic copy of $S_3$ in $S_4$ in the usual way.
Note that their intersections are trivial.
Denote the two subgroups as $H$ and $K$, then $HK$ is a subgroup of $S_4$ of size $\frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|} = 4 \cdot 6 = |S_4|$, so $HK$ is equal to $S_4$, meaning $S_4$ is a semidirect product of $V_4$ and $S_3$.

To show that $S_4 \cong V_4 \rtimes_\phi S_3$ for some isomorphism of $S_3 \to \text{Aut}(V_4)$ (rather than, more generally, some homomorphism), note that the kernel of $\phi$ must be a normal subgroup of $S_3$.
We make use of Jyrki's comment.
The only nontrivial normal subgroups of $S_3$ are $C_3$ and all of $S_3$, which includes $C_3$.
Note that $V_4$ is abelian.
If $C_3$ is in the kernel of $\phi$, then

$$\{ (h, k) \in V_4 \rtimes_\phi S_3 | h \in V_4, k \in C_3 \}$$

is an abelian subgroup of order 12.
However, $V_4$ has no abelian subgroup of order 12.
Therefore the kernel of $\phi$ must be trivial, i.e. it is an isomorphism of $S_3 \to \text{Aut}(V_4)$.

To show that $S_4$ is a semidirect product of $V_4$ and $S_3$ for any isomorphism of $S_3 \to \text{Aut}(V_4)$, see the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2516147/why-is-h-rtimes-varphi-k-isomorphic-to-h-rtimes-varphi-circ-phi-k).